# How to display a Interstitial Ad in a LibGDX project?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, interstitial

I found a Flappy Bird GitHub project and changed it a little bit. 
I successfully implemented the AdMob Banner.

But now I also want a Interstitial Ad which pops up when the Game is over (not every time of course) so here is my GitHub project: https://github.com/DaFaack/FlappyBibi

Please explain me how to do it because I can't find a good explanation on the internet.

I want to display the ad in the run() method. You can find it in the core package -> `GameplayScreen.java` File -> `renderPlaying()` method and then the `run()` method.

This is the method i am talking about:

```
    private void renderPlaying() {
        if (justTouched) {
            bird.jump();
            justTouched = false;

        }
        updatePipePairs();
        gameplayStage.act();
        uiStage.act();
        checkCollisions();
        if (bird.getState() == Bird.State.DYING) {
            stopTheWorld();


            RunnableAction playWooshAction = Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.playWooshSound();

//Here I want to display the Interstitial Ad!

                }
            });
```

What do I have to do to display the Interstitial Ad when the game is over?

This is my AndroidLauncher.java file:

```
package com.pentagames.flappybibi.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication{

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidLauncher";
    protected AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView=initializeForView(new FlappyGame(), config);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(){
                int visibility = adView.getVisibility();
                adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
                adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
                Log.i(TAG, "Ad Loaded...");
            }
        });
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX");

        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);
        adView.loadAd(builder.build());

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adView.destroy();
    }
    }
```

And this the GameplayScreen file:

```
package com.pentagames.flappybibi;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.SequenceAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Align;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class GameplayScreen extends ScreenAdapter{

    public static final float PIPE_SPACING = 200f;
    public static final int PIPE_SETS = 3;

    protected OrthographicCamera camera;
    protected com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame game;

    private Stage gameplayStage;
    private Stage uiStage;
    private Label scoreLabel;
    private Label tapToRetry;
    private Label best;
    private Label tapToFlap;
    private Image whitePixel;
    private Image backgroundBuildings;

    private int score;

    private Bird bird;
    private Array<PipePair> pipePairs;

    private com.pentagames.flappybibi.Ground ground;

    private boolean justTouched;

    private Color backgroundColor;

    private State screenState = State.PREGAME;
    private boolean allowRestart = false;

    private enum State {PREGAME, PLAYING, DYING, DEAD}

    public GameplayScreen(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT);
        gameplayStage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT, camera));
        uiStage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT));
        bird = new Bird();
        bird.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH * .25f, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT / 2, Align.center);
        bird.addAction(Utils.getFloatyAction());
        bird.setState(Bird.State.PREGAME);

        whitePixel = new Image(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.whitePixel);

        scoreLabel = new Label("0", new Label.LabelStyle(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.fontMedium, Color.WHITE));
        scoreLabel.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH / 2, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT * .9f, Align.center);
        uiStage.addActor(scoreLabel);

        tapToRetry = new Label("Nochmal?", new Label.LabelStyle(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.fontMedium, Color.WHITE));
        tapToRetry.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH / 2, 0, Align.top);
        uiStage.addActor(tapToRetry);

        best = new Label("Highscore: ", new Label.LabelStyle(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.fontMedium, Color.WHITE));
        best.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH / 2, 0, Align.top);
        uiStage.addActor(best);

        tapToFlap = new Label("Fass mich an!", new Label.LabelStyle(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.fontMedium, Color.WHITE));
        tapToFlap.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH / 2, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT, Align.bottom);
        uiStage.addActor(tapToFlap);

        initBackgroundBuildings();

        pipePairs = new Array<PipePair>();

        ground = new com.pentagames.flappybibi.Ground();
        ground.setPosition(0, 0);

        backgroundColor = Utils.getRandomBackgroundColor();

        // The order actors are added determines the order they are drawn so make sure the background is first
        gameplayStage.addActor(ground);
        gameplayStage.addActor(backgroundBuildings);
        gameplayStage.addActor(bird);

        // Setup the input processor
        initInputProcessor();
    }

    private void initBackgroundBuildings() {
        backgroundBuildings = new Image(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.backgroundBuildings);
        backgroundBuildings.setWidth(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH);
        backgroundBuildings.setHeight(backgroundBuildings.getHeight()*2f);
        backgroundBuildings.setY(com.pentagames.flappybibi.Ground.HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        tapToFlap.addAction(Actions.moveToAligned(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_X, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_Y + 100f, Align.center, .75f, Interpolation.sine));
        com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.playWooshSound();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor(backgroundColor.r, backgroundColor.g, backgroundColor.b, 1f);
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        switch (screenState) {
            case PREGAME:
                updateAndDrawStages();
                break;
            case PLAYING:
                renderPlaying();
                break;
            case DYING:
            case DEAD:
                renderDeadOrDying();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void renderDeadOrDying() {
        if (bird.getState() == Bird.State.DEAD) {
            screenState = State.DEAD;
        }
        updateAndDrawStages();
    }

    private void renderPlaying() {
        if (justTouched) {
            bird.jump();
            justTouched = false;

        }
        updatePipePairs();
        gameplayStage.act();
        uiStage.act();
        checkCollisions();
        if (bird.getState() == Bird.State.DYING) {
            stopTheWorld();

            RunnableAction playWooshAction = Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.playWooshSound();

//Here I want to display the Interstitial Ad!

                }
            });

            SequenceAction actions = Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(1f), playWooshAction, Actions.moveToAligned(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_X, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_Y, Align.bottom,
                    .75f, Interpolation.sine), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Allow the player to restart the game once the tap to retry finishes coming up
                    allowRestart = true;
                }
            }));
            tapToRetry.addAction(actions);

            best.setText("Highscore: " + com.pentagames.flappybibi.SavedDataManager.getInstance().getHighScore());
            best.setWidth(best.getTextBounds().width);
            best.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_X, 0, Align.top);
            best.addAction(Actions.delay(1f, Actions.moveToAligned(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_X, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_Y, Align.top,
                    .75f, Interpolation.sine)));

            screenState = State.DYING;
        }
        gameplayStage.draw();
        uiStage.draw();
    }

    private void updateAndDrawStages() {
        gameplayStage.act();
        gameplayStage.draw();
        uiStage.act();
        uiStage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
        com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        gameplayStage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
        uiStage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        gameplayStage.dispose();
        uiStage.dispose();
    }

    private void checkCollisions() {

        for (int i = 0; i < pipePairs.size; i++) {
            PipePair pair = pipePairs.get(i);
            if (pair.getBottomPipe().getBounds().overlaps(bird.getBounds()) || pair.getTopPipe().getBounds().overlaps(bird.getBounds())) {
                stopTheWorld();
                com.pentagames.flappybibi.SavedDataManager.getInstance().setHighScore(score);
                showWhiteScreen();
            } else if (bird.isBelowGround()) {
                bird.setY(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.GROUND_LEVEL);
                bird.clearActions();
                bird.setToDying();
                showWhiteScreen();
            } else if (bird.isAboveCeiling()) {
                bird.setY(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT - bird.getHeight());
                bird.setToDying();
                showWhiteScreen();
            } else if (pair.getRuby().getBounds().overlaps(bird.getBounds())) {
                score++;
                updateScoreLabel();
                pair.moveCoinOffscreen();
                com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.playBingSound();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showWhiteScreen() {
        whitePixel.setWidth(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH);
        whitePixel.setHeight(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT);

        gameplayStage.addActor(whitePixel);

        whitePixel.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(.5f));
    }

    private void updateScoreLabel() {
        scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        scoreLabel.setWidth(scoreLabel.getTextBounds().width);
        scoreLabel.setPosition(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.WIDTH / 2, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT * .9f, Align.center);
    }

    private void stopTheWorld() {
        bird.setToDying();
        killPipePairs();
        stopTheGround();
        screenState = State.DYING;

    }

    private void stopTheGround() {
        ground.vel.x = 0;
    }

    private void killPipePairs() {
        for (PipePair pair : pipePairs) {
            pair.getBottomPipe().setState(Pipe.State.dead);
            pair.getTopPipe().setState(Pipe.State.dead);
            pair.getRuby().setVel(0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void updatePipePairs() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pipePairs.size; i++) {
            pipePairs.get(i).update();
        }
    }

    private void addPipes(Stage gameplayStage) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pipePairs.size; i++) {
            gameplayStage.addActor(pipePairs.get(i).getBottomPipe());
            gameplayStage.addActor(pipePairs.get(i).getTopPipe());
            gameplayStage.addActor(pipePairs.get(i).getRuby());
        }
    }

    private void initThirdSetOfPipes() {
        Pipe topPipe = new Pipe();
        Pipe bottomPipe = new Pipe();
        topPipe.getRegion().flip(false, true);
        PipePair pair = new PipePair(topPipe, bottomPipe);
        pair.initThird();

        // add the pair to the list
        pipePairs.add(pair);
    }

    private void initSecondSetOfPipes() {
        Pipe topPipe = new Pipe();
        Pipe bottomPipe = new Pipe();
        topPipe.getRegion().flip(false, true);
        PipePair pair = new PipePair(topPipe, bottomPipe);
        pair.initSecond();

        // add the pair to the list
        pipePairs.add(pair);
    }

    private void initFirstSetOfPipes() {
        Pipe topPipe = new Pipe();
        Pipe bottomPipe = new Pipe();
        topPipe.getRegion().flip(false, true);
        PipePair pair = new PipePair(topPipe, bottomPipe);
        pair.initFirst();

        // add the pair to the list
        pipePairs.add(pair);
    }

    /**
     * Tells libgdx to listen for inputs coming from the InputAdapter we give it
     */
    private void initInputProcessor() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
            // We only care about the touch down event
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

                switch (screenState) {

                    case DYING:
                        justTouched = true;
                        break;

                    case DEAD:
                        if (allowRestart) {
                            game.setScreen(new GameplayScreen(game));
                        }
                        justTouched = true;
                        break;

                    case PLAYING:
                        justTouched = true;
                        break;


                    case PREGAME:
                        justTouched = true;
                        screenState = State.PLAYING;
                        bird.setState(Bird.State.ALIVE);
                        bird.clearActions();
                        tapToFlap.addAction(Actions.moveToAligned(com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.CENTER_X, com.pentagames.flappybibi.FlappyGame.HEIGHT, Align.bottom, .75f, Interpolation.sine));
                        initFirstSetOfPipes();
                        initSecondSetOfPipes();
                        initThirdSetOfPipes();
                        addPipes(gameplayStage);
                        gameplayStage.addActor(ground);
                        gameplayStage.addActor(bird);
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


}
```

This is the first time that I'm working with LibGDX, would be great if you can explain me how to implement the Interstitial Ad in this project.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already integrated banner Ad so no need to injected dependent artifact in your project.

Follow these steps for Interstitial Ad integration.

1. `AndroidManifest.xml`

   Make an entry of `AdActivity` for  Interstitial Ad

   ```
   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
   ```
2. Create an interface inside your core module

   ```
   public interface AdService {

      boolean isInterstitialLoaded();
      void showInterstitial();
   }
   ```
3. Create a parameterized constructor of `FlappyGame` class

   ```
   public AdService adService;

   public FlappyGame(AdService ads){
        adService=ads;
   }
   ```
4. Implement `AdService` interface to your `AndroidLauncher` class

   ```
   public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdService {

       private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL = "ca-app-pub-XXXXX/XXXXX";
       private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ...
            View gameView=initializeForView(new FlappyGame(this), config);
            ...

            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onAdLoaded() {}

                 @Override
                 public void onAdClosed() {
                      loadIntersitialAd();
                 }
            });

            loadIntersitialAd();
       }

       private void loadIntersitialAd(){

          AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
          interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
       }

     @Override
     public void showInterstitial() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  if (interstitialAd.isLoaded())
                     interstitialAd.show();
                  else
                     loadIntersitialAd();
                }
            });
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isInterstitialLoaded() {
           return interstitialAd.isLoaded();
      }
   }
   ```
5. `GameScreen` class

   ```
   RunnableAction playWooshAction = Actions.run(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               com.pentagames.flappybibi.Assets.playWooshSound();
                game.adService.showInterstitial();
           }
   });
   ```

I integrated Interstitial Ad in your project, created a [pull request](https://github.com/DaFaack/FlappyBibi/pull/1) for the same. You can merge my pull request.